# Ng-repeat autocomplete only works on first text box

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a web app that uses AngularJS and jQuery to perform create, read, update and delete on a list of hotels:http://jgdoherty.org/.
When "edit" is selected I am using **jQuery autocomplete** to populate the "County" text box. However the autocomplete only works on the first "County" text box in the list. If you look at the javascript code it has the autocomplete directive set on the text box that has the id "**cty**". You can see the entire js code here:http://jgdoherty.org/Scripts/Emp.js
The edit code is just this section of it (which is what I need to change):

```
 $scope.toggleEdit = function (hotel) {
            id = hotel.HotelId;
                    var array = [];
            $('#cty').autocomplete({

                source: $scope.availableTags,
                change: function (event, ui) {


                },
                messages: {
                    noResults: '',
                    Results: ''
                },

                search: function (oEvent, oUi, request, response) {


                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                       url: "http://jgdoherty.org/api/Counties/GetCounties",
                        // data: //document.getElementById('txtCounty').value,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data != null) {

                                response(data.d);

                            }
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    }).done(function (data) {

                        ($.each(data, function (val) {


                            array.push($.trim(data[val].CountyName));


                        }

                        )

                        );


                        return (array);

                    }

                     )
                    .always(function (data) {

                    })


                    // get current input value
                    var sValue = $(oEvent.target).val();

                    // init new search array
                    var aSearch = [];

                    // for each element in the main array ...
                    $(array).each(function (iIndex, sElement) {

                        // ... if element starts with input value ...
                        if ($.toString(sElement.substr(0, sValue.length)).toUpperCase == $.toString(sValue).toUpperCase) {

                            // ... add element
                            aSearch.push($.trim(sElement));


                        }
                    });
                    // change search array

                    $('#cty').autocomplete('option', 'source', aSearch);


                    array = [];
                },
                position: {

                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    dacounty2 = ui.item.value;                                   


                }

            });


            this.hotel.editMode = !this.hotel.editMode;
        };
```

I know it is something to do with the every text box after the first one being seen as a "child" but apart from that I am stuck.

Comment: Id's should be unique. `$('#cty')` will only get one element.

Comment: You should create a directive out of this instead of doing jquery  operations in your controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this after much googling. In the cshtml file (Index.cshtml) I put a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="selectedCountry" value="" />
```

In the js file (http://jgdoherty.org/Scripts/Emp.js) I added the following

```
event.preventDefault();                    
                var selectedObj = ui.item.value;                 
                $('#selectedCountry').val(selectedObj);
```

in
the body of

```
change: function (event, ui) { 
}
```

There was a slight mistake in   **$('#cty').autocomplete('option', 'source', aSearch);**. It should have been

```
$('.cty').autocomplete('option', 'source', aSearch);
```

I added

```
hotel.County = $('#selectedCountry').val();
```

to the save event: **$scope.save = function (hotel) {**

(under **id = hotel.HotelId;**)

It now does automplete under all the "county" text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [angular-autocomplete](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngAutocomplete). Sometimes when you mix Jquery and Angularjs binding problems are created.

Comment: I actually wanted to use angular autocomplete at the start (instead of jquery autocomplete) but "md-autocomplete" was giving an error "not recognised" in the cshtml code so I didn't use it.

Comment: I am using the 'ngResource' module on that page, I need to add the 'ngAutocomplete' module also.

Comment: Yes. For autocomplete you need to add it.